# AngularFire2 retrieving $value and $key

Tags: jquery, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2

im working on a simple friend add-delete page.

my data is very simple:

```
{
  "usernameToUid" : {
    "test1" : "JEhnsK6igwh69iX6pZo4cJMGL5L2",
    "test2" : "0OhZ5eE27wOkTLE8C0PQHKTkYxk1"
  },
  "users" : {
    "0OhZ5eE27wOkTLE8C0PQHKTkYxk1" : {
      "friends" : {
        "test1" : "JEhnsK6igwh69iX6pZo4cJMGL5L2"
      },
      "profile" : {
        "firstName" : "Walter",
        "lastName" : "White",
        "username" : "test2"
      }
    },
    "JEhnsK6igwh69iX6pZo4cJMGL5L2" : {
      "friends" : {
        "test2" : "0OhZ5eE27wOkTLE8C0PQHKTkYxk1"
      },
      "profile" : {
        "firstName" : "Jesse",
        "lastName" : "Pinkman",
        "username" : "test1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

there is a friends list on html and a sliding delete button;

```
 <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let friend of friendsArray; let i = index">
        <ion-item>
          <h2>{{friend.firstName}} {{friend.lastName}}</h2>
          <p> {{friend.$key}} </p>
        </ion-item>

          <ion-item-options side="right">
            <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deleteFriend(i)">
              <ion-icon name="delete"></ion-icon>
              &nbsp;Delete&nbsp;
            </button>
          </ion-item-options>
      </ion-item-sliding>
```

and .ts function:

```
deleteFriend(i) {
        console.log(this.friendsArray[i].$key)
        console.log(this.friendsArray[i].$value)
        this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.myUid}/friends/`).remove(`${this.friendsArray[i].$key}`)
        this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.friendsArray[i].$value}/friends/`).remove(`${this.myUsername}`)
}
```

in this code, friendsArray[i].$value is target users id, friendsArray[i].$key is target users username.

when i click the delete button, console perfectly returns me the $value and $key of clicked user in the list. but then, gives an error like this:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '$value' of undefined
```

i can log value and key but i cant use that in code why ? and how fix it ?

Comment: how are you getting the data `friendsArray`?

Comment: Try: `this.afDatabase.list("users/" + this.friendsArray[i].value + "/friends").remove(this.myUsername)`

Comment: getting data with that:  this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.myUid}/friends/`).subscribe(data => {
          this.friendsArray = data;

Comment: @Makah gives an error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem different and easy way, but still dont know why it worked.

just created two string variables and used them for $key and $value

```
    this.friendIndexUsername = this.friendsArray[i].$key
    this.friendIndexUid = this.friendsArray[i].$value


    this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.myUid}/friends/`).remove(`${this.friendIndexUsername}`)
    this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.friendIndexUid}/friends/`).remove(`${this.myUsername}`)
```

worked. but can somebody light me up why ?